# Electron loadURL return some unknown code rather than index.html

Tags: electron, electron-builder

In my main process I have created a BrowserWindow

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(options)
mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${app.getAppPath()}/index.html`)
```

At first the page loads successfully, but I don't know what happenes as some local images won't load.

Then I reloaded the page by `command+R` and this view (unloaded local images) is gone.

The app shows me some code in the page, I have never seen.

If I restart the app everything is well.

Answer (score 0):

Only use the [`win.loadURL(url[, options])`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options) method when loading URL's.

When loading local files, use [`win.loadFile(filePath[, options])`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options)

Use of Node's [path](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v19.x/api/path.html) module, specifically the use of the [`.join`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v19.x/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) method (in conjunction with [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname)) will help tremendously with path construction.

```js
// Import required electron modules
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

// Import the required Node modules
const path = require('path');

...

// Create the window
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(options);

// Load the html file and show the window
mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
    .then(() => { mainWindow.show(); });
```

[`app.getAppPath()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetapppath) should not be used to create the window.

Comment: If I can not use `lodaURL` when url is lodal file why the app can work?I do not think change method or url can resolve my issue.  Because we have more than 500000 users and report this issue is not often, and the issue will be missing when restart the app

Comment: Have you tried using the above code and then reloading your page? What happens?

Comment: It doesn't have to happen, it happens occasionally, and most of the time it works normally, only occasionally. So if I replace it with the above code, nothing will happen, because I don't have any problems at all. It's a problem that online users have reported back. Our app has 500000 users, and only a few users will have this problem. and they restart the app eveyting is ok.

Comment: Replacing your code with the above code may be a start in debugging. Not changing anything at all will not fix you intermittent bug. In your questions you mentioned that some local images were being shown (IE: Loaded). Can you add the code to display those images to your question? Additionally, you mention that you see some “unknown code” in your page. Adding this unknown code output to your question will assist us in helping you.

Comment: Since it's been a week since the last time it happened I forgot who reported to me...I will update this question when the error occour next time, Thanks for your help